# Smooth changing of line thickness using OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I'm drawing a few lines using `OpenGL ES` and I need to change their thickness from `1 pixel` to `3 pixels` smoothly, but `glLineWidth` doesn't allow to set line thickness between `1.0` and `2.0`.
Is it possible?

Here is my code

```
- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(thinLines), thinLines, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    self.effect.constantColor = GLKVector4Make(lineR, lineG, lineB, 1.0f);
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glLineWidth(1 + scaleQ);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, thinLinesCount*2);   
}
```

Comment: Does glLineWidth even come into effect here? You should really just adjust the vertices in your _vertexArray/_vertexBuffer, after all they define the location and thus width of whatever you're trying to draw.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D maybe he meant the thickness of the individual lines.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yes it does, but `glLineWidth` can only make line width integer, not fractional.

Comment: @rakeshbs yes, I mean, that I need to change thickness of lines, thanks. I'll fix it.

Comment: LIMITATION: opengl es (as of 3.0) does not guarantee support of glLineWidth: *"... Only width 1 is guaranteed to be supported; others depend on the implementation. ..."* - [glLineWidth at khronos.org](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glLineWidth.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES (including 3.0) does not support antialiased lines. From documentation to `glLineWidth`:

> The actual width is determined by rounding the supplied width to the
>   nearest integer.

So unfortunately you can't "smoothly" change line thickness.

Comment: And there is no way or a trick, which I can use to make it looks like smooth changing of line thickness?

Comment: Usingn GL_LINES - No. But you can try to draw line as a rectangle and 'smoothly' change one of its demention.

Comment: but how can I set this rectangle's width in pixels? Because iPhones has a different screens with different resolutions. How can I make this rectangle be 2 pixels width (for example) on all devices?

Comment: If I correctly understand you - you want a line (rectangle) to have the same visible width (thickness) on any screen. Try to set `glkView.contentScaleFactor = 1;` before any drawing. It will make connected renderBuffer to have the same size in pixels as glkView size in points. Then, if `glkView.transform` is identity, line (rectangle) will have the same visible size on any screen.

Comment: "antialiased lines" is a different topic ("antialiasing" or "multisampling" determines whether the edges of the line look smooth against whatever is behind it, vs. seeing "jaggies"). Ignore the first line of this answer - the rest of the answer is correct.